# Looping defconst to fill global-abbrev-table

Tags: abbrev

I have about 30 defconsts for abbrevs and want to loop them to fill `global-abbrev-table`.

```
(defconst tablet1 
   '( ("all" "l")     ("as" "as")      ("can" "k") ))

(defconst tablet2
   '( ("again" "ag")  ("any" "n")    ("before" "bf") ))

...

(defconst tablet30
   '( ("again" "ag")  ("any" "n")    ("before" "bf") ))


(defun abbrev ()
  (kill-all-abbrevs)
  (define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table ))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```el
(defun value-of-tablet (n)
  (symbol-value (intern (format "tablet%d" n))))

(define-abbrev-table
       'global-abbrev-table 
            (apply #'append
                   (mapcar #'value-of-tablet
                           (number-sequence 1 30))))
```

Comment: Works very well.